# TypeError: element(...).then is not a function in Protractor 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriverjs

I was using following code

```
element(by.xpath("//tf-navpane-item[contains(@class,'tf-state-selected')]//tf-navpane-item-text//*[contains(@class,'ng-binding')]")).then(function(ele){
            ele.getText().then(function(txt){
                console.log("txt: "+txt);
            });
        });
```

This code used to work fine when I was using Protractor 1.0. After upgrading Protractor to 3.2.1 ,I started to get following error.

> TypeError: element(...).then is not a function

I maybe missing something but not sure what.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, this is something you should expect since the `element()` cannot be directly resolved with `then()` anymore ([breaking change](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-2) in Protractor 2.0). Instead, do:

```
var elm = element(by.xpath("//tf-navpane-item[contains(@class,'tf-state-selected')]//tf-navpane-item-text//*[contains(@class,'ng-binding')]"));
elm.getText().then(function(txt) {
    console.log("txt: " + txt);
});
```

Note that, if you would need to assert the text, you can pass the `getText()` into `expect()` - it understands what a promise is and would resolve it before making an expectation:

```
expect(elm.getText()).toEqual("Expected text");
```

Comment: thank you. I should have gone through change-log better. :)

Comment: Saved me a lot of time !!